# Hibernate + Resteasy Maven dependency

Tags: hibernate, maven, dependencies, resteasy

someone can tell me what Hibernate and Resteasy dependencies to integrate in pom.xml?
I would create a Restful web services with this two framework.

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial, http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1185

Comment: I need a tutorial for Resteasy + DAO + Hibernate in a Maven project :/

Comment: I think googling for Resteasy and DAO/Hibernate separately will be easier. Because they are not related so much.

Comment: I know but with hibernate I'm having a lot of problems with hibernate compatibility libraries (pom.xml file).

Comment: I'm sure you will find what you are searching for [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/).

Answer (score 0):

I use resteasy + hibernate for api, what return a json object, i used the follow dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```